# Android set Superscript in CollapsingToolbarLayout/Toolbar

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I can't get HTML Spanned working with CollapsingToolbarLayout/Toolbar. I am trying to include superscript on my Toolbar title. How can I do that?

Right now, I have tried.

```
htmlTitle = String.format("%s.<sup><small>%s</small></sup>", x, y);
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(htmlTitle));
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(htmlTitle));
```

Thanks

Comment: Hint: try removing the `<small>` and `</small>` tags.